# Bluetooth discoverable on button click without navigating to bluetooth settings page

Tags: android, button, bluetooth

How can we make bluetooth discoverable  on button click without going to bluetooth settings page.

```
 bt_strength.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mBtAdapter.getScanMode()!= BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) 
           {

          make discoverable

            }
```

How can I do this?

Any help is always appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would have Bluetooth Adapter object obtained from :

```
 BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

On Button Click you can call :

```
  mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

this will put your bluetooth in **Discovery mode**